# How to determine which Python install is being used by the interpreter?

Tags: python, version, interpreter

I have several software packages that install various installs of Python.  For example:

```
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1
C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2
C:\Python27|ArcGISx6410.1
```

Using `sys.version` does not work for my case since I need to know where the actual install is located, not the version.

How can I determine which install my Python interpreter is using?

Comment: @TheSoundDefense I am not interested in determining the version, but rather the install (path) my interpreter is using.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable), which will give the path to actual interpreter executable.