# How can I get the path to the calling python executable

Tags: python

I have a series of unit tests that are meant to run in two contexts:

1) On a buildbot server
2) in developer's home environments

In both our development procedure and in the buildbot server we use virtualenv. The tests run fine in the developer environments, but with buildbot the tests are being run from the python executable in the virtualenv without activating the virtualenv.

This works out for most tests, but there are a few that shell out to run scripts, and I want them to run the scripts with the virtualenv's python executable. Is there a way to pull the path to the current python executable inside the tests themselves to build the shell commands that way?

Comment: Oops, wrong dupe. [The correct one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24895901/2301450)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current python executable is always available as `sys.executable`, which should give full path (but you can ensure this using os.path functions).